# Copy & paste Japanese text from a message box

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization, msgbox

I've just installed a proprietary VSI plugin for Visual Studio 2010. It's Japanese, and gives me this lovely message box when I try to use it:

[image: Japanese blah blah in a message box]

(Actual text hidden, can't disclose it, but it's definitely Japanese ideograms)

Problem is: I don't speak Japanese, even remotely. I would love to copy and paste this to Google Translate.

There's a nice (and quite unknown) feature in Windows message boxes: you can CTRL-C them and it puts their content in you clipboard. So I'm doing that, but here's what I get wherever I CTRL-V:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
???????????????
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Helpful, isn't it? Any idea of how to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you pasting this into?

I did an experiment...I used Character Map, chose Arial Unicode MS, and selected some ideogram characters. I copied those characters, and I could paste them into Visual Studio, or notepad and saw the ideograms.

Then I tried to replicate what you did:

I wrote a WPF program (so would be a Unicode program) with a MessageBox and used the set of ideogram characters. I ran the program, and then did a CTRL-C as you did, then I did a CTRL-V into notepad and Visual Studio.

I saw the ideograms correctly, along with the OK text, and the ------- separators.

This was on Windows 7.

You could use a Clipboard Viewer tool to see what formats/text has been placed on the clipboard.

Maybe your program VSI plugin is not built as Unicode so this affects how it places the text on the clipboard? You would ideally want CF_UNICODETEXT on the clipboard.

Comment: Looks like I only tried Notepad++ (I thought I tested the regular notepad as well, but apparently I didn't... my bad). If I paste the text to Visual Studio or notepad I get the ideograms. I also get them if I first select "Encoding > Encode in UTF-8" in the Notepad++ menu. So, thanks a lot for your investigation, issue solved!